# After php form is sent, how do I edit the 'new' confirmation page?

Tags: php, html, css

PHP contact form is sent and displays a confirmation message: I need the div with the white background to be full column. If I put margins on the message, it breaks layout as pictured. I'm still wrapping my head around how the PHP logic's structure in terms of interactions, not sure where exactly to tweak it and fix the issue.

My code is structured as such:

```html
<div id="whitebox" class="whitebox">
<div class="text-center orange-navbar">
      <nav role="navigation">
<ul class="navcen nav nav-pills" >
  <li role="presentation"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li class="active" role="presentation"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
    </div>

    
    <?php if(!empty($emailSent)): ?>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="alert alert-success text-center"><?php echo $config->get('messages.success'); ?></div>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php if(!empty($hasError)): ?>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="alert alert-danger text-center"><?php echo $config->get('messages.error'); ?></div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

[image: Contact form success response]

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
.whitebox {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

This will give your `whitebox` div a height of 100% of your viewport.

Comment: Even though this seems logic. It isn't. This only works if the element starts at the very top off the screen. Otherwise there is a guaranteed overlap (or fixes with padding/margin to fix the overlap).

Comment: Well, with the code that he provided everything lives inside of this element. Also, we would assume that he would want his navbar to always be at the top, so yes, then this element will always start at the top.

Comment: Thanks but I already have a height specified on the column. When the browser renders the final message in PHP as a 'new' page, the height is lost.

Comment: If everything is in it, i would advise a color background on the body